# extract all images from vss file

Tags: java, linux, svg, automation, visio

I've .vss file, when I open vss file using Mircrosoft Visio it contains around 35 Images now I want make all 35 images into  35 svg's. 
I'm selecting single image and save as in .svg formate, I'm doing manual

Now I want to do this automate
Is there any way to automate this in Java or any language or any tools either in linux or windows?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you want to export whole sheets as svg, or extract the embedded images?

Comment: Extract embedded images